# MATLAB table - Select first row that meets a condition

Tags: matlab

I want to select the first row that meets a certain condition. For instance lets consider the MATLAB patients sample data

```
load patients
patients = table(LastName,Age,Gender,Height,Weight,Smoker);
```

I want to select the first row that meets the condition of Gender being 'Male' and Age > 40. This would result in the patient named "Johnson" being selected.

```
subset_patients = patients(strcmp(patients.Gender, 'Male') & patients.Age>40,:)
first_Male_over40 = subset_patients(1,:);
```

Is there a way to do it in one line though, so I do not waste space creating a separate table for the subset? I tried the following but it did not work.

```
first_Male_over40 = patients(strcmp(patients.Gender, 'Male') & patients.Age>40,:)(1,:);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find(logicalIndexes, k, 'first')` as follows (`k=1` in your case):

```
first_Male_over40 = patients(find(strcmp(patients.Gender, 'Male') & (patients.Age > 40), 1, 'first'), :)
```